# unity job system for 2d or more dimmension arrays?

Tags: unity, unityscript

I need to send a 2d array to a job system but execute function of `IJobParallelFor` just accepts one dimension. This is the example:

```
public  struct CalculateJob : IJobParallelFor
    {
        public NativeArray<Vector3> vertices;


       public int rows;
       public int x, y;

        public void Execute(int i)
        {


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just flatten the 2d array into a 1d array by concatenating the rows. So a 2d array like this:

```
11111
22222
33333
```

becomes a 1d array like this:

```
111112222233333
```

Like this for example:

```
int i = 0;
for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {  
     for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
         nativeArray[i] = 2dArray[x,y];
         i++;
     }
}
```

To find the index in the 1d array which corresponds to a specific x:y coordinate pair, use the formula `i = x + y * width`. So to convert it back:

```
for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {  
     for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
         2dArray[x,y] = nativeArray[x + y * width];
     }
}
```